# is it possible to create shortcut file of one shortcut and website link

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, shortcut-file

I am using ubuntu and tomcat server to run a web application that uses `tomcat.sh` to start server
and then types link in browser to open application. I have created a shortcut to that link so by double clicking it, the browser will open specified link address.

To run I went through 2 steps:

1. start tomcat using tomcat.sh
2. open application using that link shortcut

Can I bind these 2 steps (`tomcat.sh` file and link shortcut) into 1 shortcut, so by clicking on that created shortcut, tomcat will start and the browser will open application link?

Also how do I do that on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is possible.

You could write a script which starts tomcat and then opens your url. Double clicking that script should do what you want.

For example for Windows (you could follow the same approach for linux) you could have a script like this:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Oracle\jdk1.6
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0
set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512m -server
call %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat start
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://localhost:8093/
```

Note that this script directly executes the browser (FF in this case) passing the url to be opened.

If you have created a link - let's `mywebapp` -  using the explorer with as target your url, you can just replace the line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://localhost:8093/
```

with

```
mywebapp.url  (windows only)
```

Note here the extension `.url` (windows only)

Or whatever you use to open a link from the command shell on linux.

Also you may want to give your tomcat a bit of time to start, you could use the command `timeout` on windows or `sleep` on linux and pass to each of then the amount of seconds to wait before openning your url.

Comment: hey thanks A4l ..for quick reply...i will try it today itself...hope it will work...                                                       regards Nil

Comment: @NielGupta You're welcome! I hope it'll help you find the solution you are looking for.